# Is the new Polaroid film usable for image or emulsion transfers?

Tags: large-format, polaroid

I recall playing around with Polaroid transfers when I was a child, and, as many, I greatly admire the color palette of that film. I've been wanting to introduce my 8-y-o daughter to this, but don't know if the idea is even feasible. Specifically,

1. Are any of the new instant films even suitable for transfers. From reading around, it sounds like some of the film types are not peel-apart, which, presumably, means not suitable for transfer.
2. Will [the new Holland-made 8x10 film](https://www.polaroid.com/en_us/collections/film-for-polaroid-8x10-cameras) work for transfers? (I am reasonably skilled at large format, and would consider buying an 8x10 camera if this idea pans out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one current product in peel-apart instant film: One Instant.  One Instant is using leftover materials from before old Polaroid ended production, hand assembled into 3x4 format and loaded one print/negative set per cartridge.  The 8x10 Polaroid you mention, though compatible with 8x10 Polaroid processors, is an integral film, similar except for size to current production Polaroid SX-70, 600, and iType films.

One Instant film *should* work about the same for transfers as the old peel-apart products of the same type (i.e. ISO 100 color or ISO 400 B&W) did.  I'd be rather reluctant to experiment, however, due to the cost per frame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you think of the mention of an "image lifting technique" in the official notes on the 8x10 film?  (Scroll down to the warning about the mirrored effect.) https://support.polaroid.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012555048?input_string=the+new+8x10+film

Comment: This technique works the same as with the standard Polaroid and Polaroid Go films, though it might be easier with the larger image area.  Yes, the mirror imaging is due to exposing on and viewing the same side -- Instax doesn't do this, because it exposes through the back of the print.